# Outlook Folders not Showing on iCloud Email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, sync, icloud

Updating IMAP subscribed folders doesn't help. As far as I can tell, the missing folders on icloud email are folders which were created in Outlook (in the icloud account installed there), so it seems the sync is not working the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Not know much about iCloud Email, but as I know, for IMAP email accounts in Outlook desktop client, email folders should be synced with your mail server apart from mail folder created from your Outlook desktop client side, those this computer only folders will not be synced, by designed.

So, just just check your email folders from your web mail side, and if you would like to add new email folders, it is also suggested for you to operate from your web mail side as well.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.